# How to extract JSON array stored as string in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a JSON array that looks similar to this

```
[{"key":"Email","slug":"customer-email","value":"abc@gmail.com"},{"key":"Phone Number","slug":"mobile-phone-number","value":"123456789"},{"key":"First Name","slug":"first-name","value":"abc"},{"key":"Last Name","slug":"last-name","value":"xyz"},{"key":"Date of birth","slug":"date-of-birth","value":"01/01/1990"}]
```

But the tricky part is, this array is stored as string. So I am thinking that the first step would be to convert the string into array then unnest it then follow the method in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734411/how-do-i-parse-value-from-json-array-into-columns-in-bigquery)

I wonder if this method is doable, if so I guess the challenge that I am having is to convert string into array. If not, or if you have more efficient method please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [json_extract_array](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array)

```sql
select json_extract_array(
  """[{"key":"Email","slug":"customer-email","value":"abc@gmail.com"},{"key":"Phone Number","slug":"mobile-phone-number","value":"123456789"},{"key":"First Name","slug":"first-  name","value":"abc"},{"key":"Last Name","slug":"last-name","value":"xyz"},{"key":"Date of birth","slug":"date-of-birth","value":"01/01/1990"}]""");
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  id, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_string) AS json_array
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '[{"key":"Email","slug":"customer-email","value":"abc@gmail.com"},{"key":"Phone Number","slug":"mobile-phone-number","value":"123456789"},{"key":"First Name","slug":"first-name","value":"abc"},{"key":"Last Name","slug":"last-name","value":"xyz"},{"key":"Date of birth","slug":"date-of-birth","value":"01/01/1990"}]' json_string
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_string) AS json_array
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

output is

```
Row id  json_array 
1   1   {"key":"Email","slug":"customer-email","value":"abc@gmail.com"}  
        {"key":"Phone Number","slug":"mobile-phone-number","value":"123456789"}  
        {"key":"First Name","slug":"first-name","value":"abc"}   
        {"key":"Last Name","slug":"last-name","value":"xyz"}     
        {"key":"Date of birth","slug":"date-of-birth","value":"01/01/1990"}
```

From this point  - you can use solution in [How do I parse value from JSON array into columns in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734411/how-do-i-parse-value-from-json-array-into-columns-in-bigquery)   that you referenced in your question

Comment: I have same JSON array stored as STRING in one of my column. I need to extract value of "value" i.e just email_id as result of query for entire column. How can i do it in single select query ? 
i.e string is '[{"key":"Email","slug":"customer-email","value":"abc@gmail.com"}'
How do i extract 'abc@gmail.com' as query result.